# Grid layout for deck of cards

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I have been playing with Grid. I'm not that good with CSS much less a Grid layout. I got it working but it's not quite right. And is ok as some screen sizes and overlapping each other and does not look good.

They are actually buttons with images. I would like them to be side by side and responsive. Something like this (using [] to represent a card).

```
[] [] [] [] [] []
[] []
```

The number of cards on a line would adjust to the screen width.

On Codepen, they overlap. On my WordPress site, they are side by side but still have problems with the sizes. Also, I'm not locked to grid if flex is better/easier.

```css
.btn-block {
  opacity: 0.2;
  margin: 10px 0;
}

.btn-default {
  border: none;
  background: none;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 200px;
  margin: 4px;
  padding: 0;
  width: auto;
}

.btn-default:hover {
  background: none;
}

.card-oracle-cards {
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: .5rem;
  grid-auto-rows: min-content;
  padding: 1rem;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(100px, 1fr));
}

.card-oracle-card {
  perspective: 300px;
  width: auto;
  height: 200px;
}

.card-oracle-card-body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  -webkit-transition: transform 1s;
  transition: transform 1s;
  -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  position: relative;
}

.card-oracle-card-body.is-flipped {
  -moz-transform: rotateY(180deg);
  -ms-transform: rotateY(180deg);
  -o-transform: rotateY(180deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg);
  transform: rotateY( 180deg);
}

.card-oracle-back,
.card-oracle-front,
.card-oracle-front-reverse {
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
}

.card-oracle-front,
.card-oracle-front-reverse {
  -moz-transform: rotateY(180deg);
  -ms-transform: rotateY(180deg);
  -o-transform: rotateY(180deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg);
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}

.card-oracle-front-reverse {
  -moz-transform: rotateX(180deg);
  -ms-transform: rotateX(180deg);
  -o-transform: rotateX(180deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotateX(180deg);
  transform: rotateX(180deg);
}

.card-oracle-back:hover {
  background: white;
  -moz-transform: scale(1.1);
  -ms-transform: scale(1.1);
  -o-transform: scale(1.1);
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.1);
  transform: scale(1.1);
  transition: transform .2s;
  /* Animation */
}

.card-oracle-img-btn {
  background: none;
  display: block;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

.card-oracle-rotate-image {
  -moz-transform: rotateX(180deg);
  -ms-transform: rotateX(180deg);
  -o-transform: rotateX(180deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotateX(180deg);
  transform: rotateX(180deg);
}
```

```html
<h2>Select 3 cards.</h2>
<div class="card-oracle-cards">
  <div class="card-oracle-card">
    <div class="card-oracle-card-body">
      <div class="card-oracle-back"><button type="button" value="3899" id="id3899" onclick="this.disabled = true;" class="btn btn-default clicked"><img id="back3899" src="https://cuspstudios.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/10/assetsimagesdemo_card_back-6.png" alt="back of card"></button></div>
      <div class="card-oracle-front"><img src="https://cuspstudios.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/10/assetsimagesmajor02-6.jpg"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="card-oracle-card">
    <div class="card-oracle-card-body">
      <div class="card-oracle-back"><button type="button" value="3917" id="id3917" onclick="this.disabled = true;" class="btn btn-default clicked"><img id="back3917" src="https://cuspstudios.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/10/assetsimagesdemo_card_back-6.png" alt="back of card"></button></div>
      <div class="card-oracle-front"><img src="https://cuspstudios.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/10/assetsimagesmajor04-6.jpg"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="card-oracle-card">
    <div class="card-oracle-card-body">
      <div class="card-oracle-back"><button type="button" value="3998" id="id3998" onclick="this.disabled = true;" class="btn btn-default clicked"><img id="back3998" src="https://cuspstudios.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/10/assetsimagesdemo_card_back-6.png" alt="back of card"></button></div>
      <div class="card-oracle-front"><img src="https://cuspstudios.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/10/assetsimagesmajor13-6.jpg"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="card-oracle-card">
    <div class="card-oracle-card-body">
      <div class="card-oracle-back"><button type="button" value="3908" id="id3908" onclick="this.disabled = true;" class="btn btn-default clicked"><img id="back3908" src="https://cuspstudios.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/10/assetsimagesdemo_card_back-6.png" alt="back of card"></button></div>
      <div class="card-oracle-front"><img src="https://cuspstudios.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/10/assetsimagesmajor03-6.jpg"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="card-oracle-card">
    <div class="card-oracle-card-body">
      <div class="card-oracle-back"><button type="button" value="3980" id="id3980" onclick="this.disabled = true;" class="btn btn-default clicked"><img id="back3980" src="https://cuspstudios.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/10/assetsimagesdemo_card_back-6.png" alt="back of card"></button></div>
      <div class="card-oracle-front"><img src="https://cuspstudios.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/10/assetsimagesmajor11-6.jpg"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="card-oracle-card">
    <div class="card-oracle-card-body">
      <div class="card-oracle-back"><button type="button" value="4043" id="id4043" onclick="this.disabled = true;" class="btn btn-default clicked"><img id="back4043" src="https://cuspstudios.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/10/assetsimagesdemo_card_back-6.png" alt="back of card"></button></div>
      <div class="card-oracle-front"><img src="https://cuspstudios.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/10/assetsimagesmajor18-6.jpg"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="card-oracle-card">
    <div class="card-oracle-card-body">
      <div class="card-oracle-back"><button type="button" value="3989" id="id3989" onclick="this.disabled = true;" class="btn btn-default clicked"><img id="back3989" src="https://cuspstudios.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/10/assetsimagesdemo_card_back-6.png" alt="back of card"></button></div>
      <div class="card-oracle-front"><img src="https://cuspstudios.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/10/assetsimagesmajor12-6.jpg"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="card-oracle-card">
    <div class="card-oracle-card-body">
      <div class="card-oracle-back"><button type="button" value="4061" id="id4061" onclick="this.disabled = true;" class="btn btn-default clicked"><img id="back4061" src="https://cuspstudios.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/10/assetsimagesdemo_card_back-6.png" alt="back of card"></button></div>
      <div class="card-oracle-front"><img src="https://cuspstudios.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/10/assetsimagesmajor20-6.jpg"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="card-oracle-card">
    <div class="card-oracle-card-body">
      <div class="card-oracle-back"><button type="button" value="3935" id="id3935" data-value="3935" onclick="this.disabled = true;" class="btn btn-default clicked"><img id="back3935" src="https://cuspstudios.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/10/assetsimagesdemo_card_back-6.png" alt="back of card"></button></div>
      <div class="card-oracle-front-reverse"><img src="https://cuspstudios.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/10/assetsimagesmajor06-6.jpg"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="card-oracle-card">
    <div class="card-oracle-card-body">
      <div class="card-oracle-back"><button type="button" value="3953" id="id3953" onclick="this.disabled = true;" class="btn btn-default clicked"><img id="back3953" src="https://cuspstudios.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/10/assetsimagesdemo_card_back-6.png" alt="back of card"></button></div>
      <div class="card-oracle-front"><img src="https://cuspstudios.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/10/assetsimagesmajor08-6.jpg"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="card-oracle-card">
    <div class="card-oracle-card-body">
      <div class="card-oracle-back"><button type="button" value="3881" id="id3881" onclick="this.disabled = true;" class="btn btn-default clicked"><img id="back3881" src="https://cuspstudios.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/10/assetsimagesdemo_card_back-6.png" alt="back of card"></button></div>
      <div class="card-oracle-front"><img src="https://cuspstudios.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/10/assetsimagesmajor00-6.jpg"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="card-oracle-card">
    <div class="card-oracle-card-body">
      <div class="card-oracle-back"><button type="button" value="4025" id="id4025" data-value="4025" onclick="this.disabled = true;" class="btn btn-default clicked"><img id="back4025" src="https://cuspstudios.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/10/assetsimagesdemo_card_back-6.png" alt="back of card"></button></div>
      <div class="card-oracle-front-reverse"><img src="https://cuspstudios.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/10/assetsimagesmajor16-6.jpg"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: please add a drawing of the intended layout.

Comment: Just a basic side by side, using [] as a card it would look like this and number of cards based on screen width:  [] [] [] []  [] [] []